# page not found 404 error for dom-parser in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, domparser

I am trying to parse a web page using dom-parser in nodejs. when i hit request through this, it shows 404 not found error but the page can be browsed using browser. here is my code.

```
    var request = require("request");
    var DomParser = require('dom-parser');
    var parser = new DomParser();
    app.get("/parse", (req, res)=>{
    
    request({uri: "https://www.propertyfinder.ae"}, 
    function(error, response, body) {
    res.status(200).send(body)
    });
});
```

I couldn't understand why this is happening. Please help me sort this out. any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) was deprecated over two years ago. Don't use it.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for replying, which one you recommend ?